# Develop backend (Spring) without frontend (angular)?

Tags: angularjs, spring, angular, spring-boot, frontend

I am programming a spring-boot project. I only want to create the backend. Another developer will later on create the frontend with AngularJS.

I want to develope my backend without spending to much effort to create a test-frontend, since I dont know anything about JSP,Angular..

What should my Controllers(@Requestmapprings) return (Model, ModelAndView,JSON-Objects, Strings, ...??), so the angular-developer can use them for creating the view?

Is there any easy way to develop my backend without creating a frontend at all and still being able to test it somehow? I dont want to spend time to create basic Forms/Buttons/checkboxex but i would like to check if my scripts are working..

Comment: Read the guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/, and write automated tests for your services: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html. You'd better read all the relevant spring boot and spring documentation to learn about the framework, because these are quite essential things to know before starting to write an API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must start looking into REST services.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

To see how it is consumed by angular please refer.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

You can get lots of tutorials and documentation on developing REST services independent of frontend.

Comment: Second link to consume using angular https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking micro services approach based on the UI requirement and then segregate the services based on the functionality. This would make the code maintainability and development easier. If you are going to use spring-framework, it has vast stack of features, which are production ready.